# Adding 6 days to created_at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails, and working on an exercise, hope you can help me.

Inside a list of items, I need to display the date of creation of each item, and number of days until that due date.

Each item should only be valid for 7 days, so i tried to use `created_at` field since I already have it as the date of creation, but it didn't work.

I have this:

```
You created this item <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago
The due date for this item is <%= @duedate %>
```

and this:

```
@duedate = Item.find(params[:id])created_at+6.days
```

How can i add 6 days to the date of creation of the item?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get an error? Or is it not displaying correctly? What does `it hasnt worked/it didnt work` mean?

Comment: sorry i wasn't more specific.
The error msg was that the @duedate var was not found. 
And when it was, i had

`
@duedate = Item.find(params[:id])created_at+6.days
`
instead of
```
@duedate = Item.find(params[:id]).created_at+6.days
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@duedate = Item.find(params[:id]).created_at+6.day
```

As an added bonus, it'd be wise to split up this statement (because id may not always be passed):

```
@duedate = Item.find(params[:id])
raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @duedate.blank?
date = @duedate.created_at+6.day
```

Comment: thanks, but i did that and got a "couldn't find item without an id" error... tried both versions you did...what else could be wrong? (changed comment)

Comment: It's funny I gave you that little bonus because it's already doing work for you! You're passing nil for :id

Comment: How are you making the request? When you call the action that contains this code, you need to pass in the `:id`. `params[:id]` is a call on the request body looking for a passed value from the key, `:id`. Since you're not passing the param `id` in your request, you're essentially doing: `@duedate = Item.find(nil)` where find is looking for an int.

Comment: basically what you suggested was right, i found the trouble.
\